# Keep ProFTPD user in his home Folder

Tags: users, home, proftpd

I'm have setup a ProFTPd user on my Debian based Nas system for Backups with his default folder. Now I want to ensure that this user only have access to his to his folder. I have read something about it and I have found something that I have to put `defaultroot ~` in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf. But if I do this all my FTP user has to stay in their home folders is that right? And how to disallow only one user to change from his home folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second paramter to `DefaultRoot ~`, a `group-expression` which may be:

```
DefaultRoot ~ !group_not_chrooted
```

this means that members of this group won't be chrooted.
or

```
DefaultRoot ~ group1
```

this means that only members of these groups will be chrooted.
So you can add group for user you don't want to be restricted to their directories or you can add a single group for this user and add this group as a second parameter. Also note:

```
DefaultRoot ~ group1,group2
```

will `chroot` users who are members of both group1 **and** group2